# Unsatisfied Link Error in Blackberry/Java eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry

I've mangaed to get a suite of Junit tests running against a blackberry project by importing them as seperate projects in eclipse. 60 some-odd tests run correctly without any problems but 2 new ones that test behavior that uses the Arrays.sort native method are now throwing Unsatisfied Link Errors:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: net.rim.device.api.util.Arrays.sort([Ljava/lang/Object;Lnet/rim/device/api/util/Comparator;)V
    at net.rim.device.api.util.Arrays.sort(Native Method)
    at com.rapidftr.controllers.ViewController.sortByLocationThenName(ViewController.java:34)
    at com.rapidftr.controllers.ViewController.show(ViewController.java:28)
    at com.rapidftr.controllers.ViewControllerTest.shouldFetchFromServiceAndPushIntoScreen(ViewControllerTest.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:46)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Thrown
>   if the Java Virtual Machine cannot
>   find an appropriate native-language
>   definition of a method declared
>   native.

The JVM is not finding a native-language definition of Arrays.sort

Comment: This might be grossly naive, but the blackberry api that has Arrays.sort is in the build path for the test project. That's not enough?